# What is the purpose of this Placeholder in the default template?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013

When you generate a new default WebForms app in Visual Studio 2013 Update 4, you get the following in the head section:

```
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title><%: Page.Title %> - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
        <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
    <webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" />
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
</head>
```

Can anyone explain the purpose of this rather odd PlaceHolder control?  It's clearly not there so that you can actually replace content at runtime, since there is no ID associated with it.  And it does not seem to be there to help with the redering of the bundles, since the bundles render just fine without the PlaceHolder.

I'm at a loss to understand why the ASP.NET team thought this PlaceHolder control should be there, and see no purpose for it.  Is it merely an error?  Was it intended to have an ID so it could be replaced at runtime?  Or is there something I'm missing here?

The only thing I can think of is that `Scripts.Render()` might look at its parent for something, but I can't find any evidence of that by looking at the source.

**Does this control, as written, serve a purpose?  What is it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It avoids this error:

> The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control
>   contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).

This error is fairly easy to generate by adding controls to the `head` element at runtime (e.g. dynamic meta tags).

```
protected override void OnInit( EventArgs e )
{
    // will throw without placeholder            
    Header.Controls.Add( new HtmlGenericControl( "meta" ) );

    base.OnInit( e );
}
```

If there are no dynamic controls in the header, then the placeholder is probably superfluous.

Comment: So why doesn't the title element cause the same problem?

Comment: You're absolutely right though.. Apparently, the title tag is "special", and the rules don't apply to it.